# Is there anything that I can do with Perl/Python but C# would not do?

Tags: c#, java, python, perl, scripting

I have done some development in C# and I love the language and the environment. I am taking a Perl class, and yes it sounds like easy learning curve, but there are some questions which I think need to be asked essentially as a server-side developer.

So far, if I want to create a stripped-down program which runs on a Windows machine then I can create a console application. C# + .NET are good enough that I can achieve most of the functionality.

Now, when scripting languages come into picture, I agree that they are easy to use and easy to write. The languages have super-rich functional libraries. But is is just a choice that we make to use a scripting language as opposed to a fully-fledged framework like .NET? Or are there some things that only scripting languages can do, and would be very difficult to achieve from languages like C# and Java?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is tag spamming.

Comment: what is tag spamming?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [help/dont-ask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: @Californicated: Soner is talking about the number of high-traffic tags you used to get attention for a question that is not on-topic for the site.

Comment: Short answer for an off-topic question: (1) I enjoy not having to recompile my programs after each change. Scripting languages FTW. (2) For some kinds of tasks, scripting languages are far more expressive – what takes 100 lines of boilerplate in C# might be done in 50 lines of Perl. (3) Most of the time, I don't need the performance of languages like Java, and can be done much quicker in Python. (4) Some excellent libraries are language-specific, e.g. C# doesn't have numpy, Java's regexes are primitive compared with Perl's capabilities.

Comment: The short answer is no, there is nothing you can do in Perl or Python that a C-like language will not do. But that doesn't mean you should write everything in C#, far from it: you should use the language that makes development as swift as possible, and rewrite in C as a last resort if you absolutely *must* have the run-time performance that it gives.

Comment: @Californicated: Tag spamming is what you probably think it is: adding so many tags to your questions that it will draw in experts from too wide a variety of expertise.

Comment: @Californicated: I would also encourage you to learn a language that isn't tied to a particular platform. You won't find a job using your C# experience unless you are programming for Windows. On the other hand, you will find Perl and C used universally. Hedge your bets

Answer (score 2):

C# is [Turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_Complete), so the answer to your question is "no".

.NET has nothing to do with your question; other languages have their own "full fledged framework"s (or more than one).

Comment: Turing completeness is a red herring. All “real” programming languages  have this trait, but there are definitively more expressive and less expressive languages. You are free to stick to COBOL for the rest of your life if you disagree, I'd rather keep hacking Perl ;-)

Comment: @amon: I was trying to point out the meaninglessness of the question by actually answering it.

Comment: @ysth: But Perl is also Turing-complete, so you have answered nothing. The difference between them is in their low-level access to the hardware layer. A C program can access it directly, but Perl has to rely on XS-coded library modules

Comment: @Borodin: ? I answered the question "Is there anything that I can do with Perl/Python but C# would not do?"  In any case, C# also has no low-level access to the hardware layer.